# Install 'Employees Sample Database' on MySQL (Windows 8.1) through Command line

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, installation, sample

I am trying to install the 'Employees Sample Database' in `MySQL` through command prompt. I have downloaded the `employees_db-full-1.0.6.tar.bz2`. I extracted the same and wish to install it through the command line. I am using a `Windows8.1` machine.

Please help me with the proper commands or any other way if any. The commands on `MySQL`'s site work for a `Linux` machine. Its not working for Windows.
Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

on windows, you should do this:

1, login into mysql

> 2, mysql>source "your employees.sql path";

to create a schema for the sample database. you will get error message, just ignore it. the path should be like "c:/user/sss/downloads/employees_db/employees.sql"

> 3, mysql>source "your load_employees.dump path";
>
> 4, mysql>source "your load_titles.dump path";
>
> 5, mysql>source "your load_salaries.dump path";
>
> 6, mysql>source "your load_departments.dump path";
>
> 7, mysql>source "your load_dept_emp.dump path";
>
> 8, mysql>source "your load_dept_manager.dump path";

it has to be imported in this fixed sequence, because of the database structures (dependencies of primary keys and foreign keys)

now you should have employees database installed in your mysql.

good luck.

I learnt this from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get ?

Are you referring to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html).

It simply tells to import the employees.sql. That step should work on windows too.